# Use next zoom level for low-dpi raster tiles in Mapbox to have high-res raster tiles

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

The iOS `MKMapView`, if you supply it a raster source that is in 256x256 pixels, will load the four tiles of the same region that are +1 zoom-level. Therefore it seems as if the tiles are in high-dpi-mode. Awesome!

Now I have an app that uses a third party source of raster tiles. The problem is that the data looks horribly low-dpi.

Is there a way to tell Mapbox that it should load the next zoom level of each tile of a given source and use that instead?

So instead of loading tile `0/0/0.jpg` for the whole world it should load `1/0/0.jpg`, `1/1/0.jpg`, `1/0/1.jpg` and `1/1/1.jpg` and use those for zoom level 0. So basically instead of having one 256x256 image it would have four of them, giving it a 512x512 image that looks much crisper.

The question would be... is there a way to do that not only for iOS, but in the description of the source? So that it works for Web and Android as well?

Comment: What does your request URL look like for your images?

Comment: It's just a regular URL with `{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg` at the end. But I guess that does not affect the answer, right?

Comment: That does help. I'll put my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a 512X512 tile from Mapbox using the `@2x` flag on your request for both [Raster](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-raster-tiles) and [Vector](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-vector-tiles) tiles

Your query should look like this. Notice the `@2x` right before the query string:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/1/0/0@2x.png?access_token={access_token}
```

Comment: Yes... but my url is one that does not offer 512px images... Only 256... And I'd like to know if it's somehow possible to tell Mapbox to upscale them by combining 4 tiles into one...

Comment: Oh I see. I think I misread your original question. The tiles that you have coming in from your 3rd party are what are low resolution, yes?

Comment: Exactly. And Apple-Maps would go ahead and instead of fetching f.e. one tile for zoom level 10, it would auto-fetch 4 tiles for zoom level 11 and stitch those to one bigger tile for zoom level 10... Would be great to be able to do the same with mapbox

Answer (score 0):

Why not just upscale the 256 image in your tile overlay subclass?

```
- (void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path result:(void (^)(NSData *, NSError *))result {

    if (!result) {
        return;
    }

    self.tileSize = CGSizeMake(512, 512);

    NSString *URLString = [self.internalTemplate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{x}" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)path.x]];
    URLString = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{y}" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)path.y]];
    URLString = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{z}" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)path.z]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        UIImage *resized = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(512, 512)];

        result(UIImagePNGRepresentation(resized), error);

    }];
    [task resume];

}

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```